# Simple repeat or loop Call sub in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, call

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to "loop" a sub to do a number of times.

I would like to do the following:

```
 Sub defined()
   'code here to be looped
  End sub

 Sub use()
 ... 'previous codes
 Call defined 'do defined once
 ... 'interlude codes
 Call defined(3) 'do defined action thrice
 ... 'interlude codes
 Call defined(2) 'do defined twice
 End Sub
```

Is there something like that exist? Or I must use Loop, something I still am a little confused on how to code when applying this method with a call sub.

Thank you for your time.
edited for tags

Comment: No, you need to use a `Loop`/`For`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me know how I can upvote your comment, and how to close this question. I can't see any images so you'll need to tell me where (eg, "to the left of my username"). Have a great week!

Comment: If one of the answers below suits your needs, you can accept it. The icon is located below the downvote and vote count on the left of the answer

Comment: edit: nevermind, I had to refresh to see the alt when hovering over a link and it told me that I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub Defined(numCalls as Integer)
Dim i as Integer
If not numCalls > 0 Then Exit Sub
For i = 1 to numCalls

'The rest of your code


Next

End Sub
```

This will allow you to do:

```
Call defined(3)
```

Etc.

Comment: Thank you David! It worked beautifuly. I will need to study on what  ` numCalls ` and ` Next ` does. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `numCalls` is simply a variable local to the subroutine "Defined" (you could name it anything, really, I just chose `numCalls`.  You use this variable to control how many times the sub will loop itself.  `Next` is part of the `For/Next` loop construct, which I use inside the sub to control how many times the sub loops itself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1 to 3
     Defined   '("Call" is optional)
next i
```